# Checking C++11 support for "regex": not supported

Tags: c++11, arangodb

When I trying to compile ArangoDB 3.0, I am getting this issue as below.

```
wget https://www.arangodb.com/repositories/Source/ArangoDB-3.0.0.tar.gz
tar -xvvf ArangoDB-3.0.0.tar.gz
ln -s ArangoDB-3.0.0 arangodb

     OR

git clone https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb
cd arangodb 
git checkout 3.0
git pull
```

I have tried both above binary for compile as below.

```
cd arangodb/
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Executing `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` command give me following error.

```
-- Checking C++11 support for "regex"
CMake Error at cmake/CheckCXX11Features.cmake:129 (message):
  Checking C++11 support for "regex": not supported
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/CheckCXX11Features.cmake:150 (cxx11_check_feature)
  CMakeLists.txt:265 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ec2-user/arangodb/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

OS version on AWS Linux AMI:

Linux 4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 1 22:22:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

GCC version:

```
gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: `regex` support was added in gcc 4.9. Your compiler is too old.

Comment: @BillLynch can it will upgrade or need to compile new one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `Regex` support was added in gcc 4.9
>   - @[Bill-Lynch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47453/bill-lynch)

You have two options:

- Install a newer compiler.
- Go through the code and replace all regexes with equivalent functions.

Comment: Please tell me, how can I install a new compiler? Thanks.

Comment: @akki First you need to decide which compiler you want. Tgen you do whatever is usually done on your platform / OS of choice.